# Json data creation for nlohmann

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have some data like

```
{
"GLOBAL DATA":
    {
    "FIRST": [
                {"BEGIN": "0", "END" : "100"}
             ],
    "SECOND":"SomeData",
    "THIRD":"SomeMoreData"
    }
}
```

I want to add more data to `FIRST` array.
I tried creating the insertion data as follows

`json v2 = {"BEGIN": "200","END" : "300"};`

But this gives error

`example1.cpp:34:23: error: expected '}' before ':' token json v2 = {"BEGIN": "200","END" : "300"};`

What's the issue with my `v2` data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the JSON data in a raw string literal and use the `_json` [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to parse it:

```
json v2 = R"({"BEGIN": "200", "END": "300"})"_json;
```

Or you could make it directly (without parsing), but using valid C++ syntax:

```
json v2 = {{"BEGIN", "200"}, {"END", "300"}};
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to findout this in the documentation.

Comment: @InQusitive Great! :)

Answer (score 1):

analyze pretty much what you want to do:

this here:

```
{"BEGIN":"0","END":"100","MIDDLE":50}
```

is an object at index 0 in the hierarchy:

```
globalData.first
```

so you can do get the element at index 0 in the array and add a new key:value

```
std::string st = "{\"GLOBAL DATA\":{\"FIRST\": [{\"BEGIN\": \"0\", \"END\" : \"100\"}],\"SECOND\":\"SomeData\",\"THIRD\":\"SomeMoreData\"}}";
nlohmann::json second = nlohmann::json::parse(st);
second["GLOBAL DATA"]["FIRST"].at(0).push_back({"MIDDLE", 50});
std::cout << second.dump().c_str();
```

the output:

```
{"GLOBAL DATA":{"FIRST": [{"BEGIN":"0","END":"100","MIDDLE":50}],"SECOND":"SomeData","THIRD":"SomeMoreData"}}
```